# Vector Division in a Basic Physics Problem - Is this defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, dimensional-analysis

Okay, so I am modelling a problem where I have two objects $a$ and $b$, each with a certain initial position, ${x}_a (0)$ and ${x}_b (0)$, respectively, and each with a certain velocity ${\dot{x}_a}$ and ${\dot{x}_b}$.  This problem reduces to a two dimensional problem such that ${x_a}, {x_b}, {\dot x_a}, {\dot x_b} \in \mathbb R^2$.

I'm trying to determine what direction for ${\dot x_a}$ is optimal given fixed $||{\dot x_a}||$ and fixing all other variables.

In the process of examining this problem, I did the following algebra:

The position after time $t$ of each of the objects is as follows:

$${x_a} (t) = {x_a} (0) + {\dot x_a}t$$ $${x_b} (t) = {x_b} (0) + {\dot x_b}t$$

Since we want to know when these two meet:

$$ {x_a} (0) + {\dot x_a}t - {x_b} (0) - \dot x_b t =0$$

Blindly doing algebra to this, I got the following function $f$ that maps $\dot x_a$ to $t$:

$$ t = f(\dot x_a) =  \frac{x_b - x_a}{\dot x_a - \dot x_b}$$

Given this, it seems like it would be helpful to take $\nabla f$, but I'm not sure this is actually intelligible.

If I do unit analysis, it makes sense:

$$\frac{x_b - x_a}{\dot x_a - \dot x_b} = \frac{\text {m} - \text {m}}{\frac{\text {m}}{\text {s}} - \frac{\text {m}}{\text {s}}} = \frac{\text {m} }{\frac{\text {m}}{\text {s}} } = \text{m} \cdot \frac{\text{s}}{\text{m}} = \text{s} $$

But the problem is that I have a vector in $\mathbb R^2$ divided by another vector in $\mathbb R^2$ that should, in principle, give me scalar (or maybe time should be thought of as a vector in $\mathbb R^1$?).  I'm not sure this actually works or if I've just abused the algebra.  Is vector division actually a defined operation that I can use?

**Further Developments:**

So I tried a few things just to see what would happen, so I set up this simplified problem (dropping units for readability:

Object $q$ at time $t = 0 $ is located at $x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 
\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and traveling at a velocity $\dot x = \begin{bmatrix} 10 
\\12 \end{bmatrix}$.  At what time does $x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 5 
\\6 \end{bmatrix}$?

Our function is:

$$ x(t) = x(0) + \dot x(t) $$

Plugging in the knowns:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\12 \end{bmatrix}t =  \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix}$$

We can get rid of the zero vector:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\12 \end{bmatrix}t =  \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now to isolate the $t$, we do the following operation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{10} && \frac{1}{12} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\12 \end{bmatrix}t =  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{10} && \frac{1}{12} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$2t = 1$$

$$t = \frac{1}{2}$$

All well and good, but then if we make $\dot x = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ 13 \end{bmatrix}$, meaning we miss $x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$, we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\13 \end{bmatrix}t =  \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{10} && \frac{1}{13} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\13 \end{bmatrix}t =  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{10} && \frac{1}{13} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$2t = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{13} = \frac{25}{26}$$

$$t = \frac{25}{52}$$

But:

$$\frac{25}{52} \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\13 \end{bmatrix} \ne  \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\6 \end{bmatrix}$$

What just happened?  My understanding from a bit of the math I've learned in quantum mechanics was that:

$$ | \psi \rangle = | \phi \rangle \implies \langle \xi | \psi \rangle = \langle \xi | \phi \rangle $$

This would seem to make some kind of contradiction.  What happing?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for $t$ satisfying $\vec{u} = t\vec{v}$ where $\vec{u}=x_b(0)-x_b(a)$ and $\vec{v} = \dot{x}_a-\dot{x}_b$.

If you divide component-wise and get the same quotient (i.e. $u_1/v_1 = u_2/v_2$), then $t$ is this common quotient. (e.g. if $\vec{u}=(2,3)$ and $\vec{v} = (4, 6)$, then $t=0.5$).

Otherwise $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are not parallel, so there is no such $t$. In your original problem, this corresponds to the case where the two objects never meet.

Answer (score 0):

Vector division is not defined uniquely. Complex division is defined. Since you are working in two dimensions, you *might* be able to use complex numbers instead.

[Vector division](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorDivision.html)

[Complex division](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDivision.html)